# How to remove index controller name from url in zend framwork 1.2?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend framework v1.2 for my work. and I have a controller `IndexController` containing few methods like

```
indexAction() -----------> www.website.com/index/index

howitworksAction() ---> www.website.com/index/howitworks

pricingAction()  ---> www.website.com/index/pricing

contactAction()  ---> www.website.com/index/contact
```

but I need without `index` in url like

```
www.website.com/howitworks

www.website.com/pricing

www.website.com/contact
```

I have my **config.ini** in the application folder. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following .htaccess into your public directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /add_path_to_your_public_directory_here

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in run.php, this always works for me.

```
$variable_name = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'module_name/howitworks',
    array(
        'module'        => 'module_name',
        'controller'    => 'index',
        'action'        => 'howitworks'
    )
);

$this->addRoute('variable_name', $variable_name);
```